# Почему не загружает ресурс?

Tags: java

Добрый день, понять не могу почему перестало загружать ресурс работаю в eclipse, состав проекта и расположение файла не изменял он в паке resources

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

но вдруг стало выдавать ошибку.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
>       at com4j_example.Main.main(Main.java:68)

Для загрузки пользуюсь данной конструкцией

```
InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("date.txt"); 
    System.out.println(in);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
    FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream("C://Users/Desktop/resources/date.txt//");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;

    while ((count=din.read(buffer)) != -1){ 
        outF.write(buffer,0,count);
    }
    outF.flush();
    outF.close();
```

Comment: Что за ide? Какой jar она построит? Открыть его в архиваторе (jar на самом деле обычный zip) и посмотреть в какую папку попал ресурс. Может надо делать так Main.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/com4j_example/date/date.txt");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решилось добавлением папки resources в паку bin в проекте, а дальше в пакет к классам проекта. 
Путь получился такой

> bin/"имя пакета"/resources/date.txt